# PDO and prepared statements on dynamic sized queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am developing  a small gaming website for college fest where users attend few contests and based on their ranks in `result` table, points are updated in their `user` table. Then the `result` table is truncated for the next event. The schemas are as follows:

`user`

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
user_id   |   name    |    college    |    points    |   
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

`result`

```
---------------------------
user_id   |    score
---------------------------
```

Now, the first 3 students are given 100 points, next 15 given 50 points and others are given 10 points each.

Now, I am having problem in developing queries because I don't know how many users will attempt the contest, so I have to append that many `?` in the query. Secondly, I also need to put `)` at the end.

My queries are like

```php
$query_top3=update user set points =points+100 where id in(?,?,?);
$query_next5=update user set points = points +50 where id in(?,?,?,?,?);
$query_others=update user set points=points+50 where id in (?,?...........,?);
```

How can I prepare those queries dynamically? Or, is there any better approach?

**EDIT**

Though its similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition),but in my scenario I have 3 different dynamic queries.

Comment: Are you storing `points` in result table for one event only or multiple events at a time?

Comment: @sam:I mentioned it already that `score` is only for one event and for the next event the `result` table is truncated.The `user` table exists forever and it will decide the winners when fest is over.

Comment: Maybe this can help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your requirements you can rank results and update users table (adding points) all in one query

```sql
UPDATE users u JOIN
(
  SELECT user_id,
  (
    SELECT 1 + COUNT(*)
      FROM result
     WHERE score >= r.score
       AND user_id <> r.user_id
  ) rank
    FROM result r
) q 
    ON u.user_id = q.user_id
   SET points = points + 
       CASE 
         WHEN q.rank BETWEEN 1 AND  3 THEN 100
         WHEN q.rank BETWEEN 4 AND 18 THEN  50
         ELSE 10 
       END;
```

It totally dynamic based on the contents in of `result` table. You no longer need to deal with each `user_id` individually.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ce5d/1)** demo